# Read specific messages using Apache Kafka and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I want to build an API with NodeJS and Kafka, which can take an offset and a topic as an input and output the first 10 messages starting from the offset. I tried this approach with [No-Kafka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-kafka) and [Kafka-Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node).

The consumer API provided by them allows consuming messages from a particular offset. I want to stop consuming the messages once I have read around 10 messages. But both the API calls will continue to fetch the messages till the last message. How can I stop doing that?

Here is my **EDITED FULL CODE**

```
var Kafka = require('no-kafka');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var producer = new Kafka.Producer();
producer.init().then(function() {
  console.log("Producer Ready");
});

var consumer = new Kafka.SimpleConsumer();
consumer.init().then(function() {
  console.log("Consumer Ready");
});

app.get('/produce/:topic/:msg', function(req, res) {
  producer.send({
    topic: req.params.topic,
    partition: 0,
    message: {
      value: req.params.msg
    }
  });
  res.send("Added: " + req.params.msg + " to topic: " + req.params.topic);
});

app.get('/consume/:topic/:off', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Request for topic: " + req.params.topic + " Offset: " + req.params.off);
  consumer.subscribe(req.params.topic, 0, {
    offset: req.params.off,
    maxBytes: 1000
  }, function(messageSet, topic, partition) {
    var msg = "";
    var size = messageSet.length;
    //console.log(messageSet);
    messageSet.some(function(m) {
      msg += m.message.value.toString('utf8') + " ";
      if (parseInt(m.offset, 10) > parseInt(req.params.off, 10) + 10) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    res.send("Thank you " + size + "  " + req.params.off + "  " + msg);
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Any response in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really stop consuming from Kafka so abruptly, for a couple of different reasons. For one thing, Kafka consumers, whether JavaScript or something else, don't read a message at a time -- they fetch batches of messages. I know with `kafka-node` it seems like they come in one at a time, since you get an `EventEmitter` event for each message. But under the hood, the client fetches them in batches.

The best you can do is to to keep track of your offsets as you go, and when you get outside of the range you want just to ignore them, and then unsubsribe the topic or close the consumer to stop listening.

This definitely gets trickier with partitions -- you have to keep track of offsets relative to all of your partitions. I don't do the same thing you do -- my typical use case is to read from a point in time up to the current offset for each partition. So I have not optimized my partition reads to die out as soon as they hit their last offset. I do `addTopics` and add all the partions at once. You, on the other hand, probably need to add the partitions one at a time -- i.e. do `addTopic` for a specific partition, read that partition until you find your offset, then ignore messages and `removeTopic` on the partition.

I believe I played around with that flow, and you might even have to stand up a new consumer for each partition, not to mention a whole new client.

Comment: I have a single partition for now. Ignoring the offsets beyond my range are making my other simultaneous requests slow. I am not sure how I can unsubscribe the consumer. One more thing, if two or more consumers provide different offsets to consumer API and the EventEmitter provides messages one by one, how can I identify which message was requested by which consumer?

Comment: Use more than one consumer -- which means more than one client. It's the only way I can get it to work. The pattern I use is this: I treat historical records in the stream differently than future records. If I want to read historical data, I stand up a new Client + Consumer, and grind through what I need to grind through. To set up a listener to read future data, I multiplex the listener -- if two consumers want to listen to the same topic for future requests I let them use the same consumer.

Comment: Can you suggest some code that can provide my functionality? The code I have shown in question works correctly, but it takes around 1 sec for each response.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like `kafka-node`, but looks alright to me. And I have no reason to think 1 sec is reasonable or unreasonable given what are trying to do. If I remember correctly, I had timed all of this pretty closely at some point and it took maybe 10 milliseconds to connect a client to a partition and read any data whatsoever. Then I could read about 10,000 per second.

Comment: The above code is written with no-Kafka. I am also unable to debug the reason for it. Currently, I have a very simplified system wherein 1 have single partition, multiple topics and my NodeJS server is the same as Kafka server. I am editing the question to provide my full code for this task. Since the event emitter with kafka-node provides one message at a time, it makes it difficult for me to handle consumers for it.

Comment: What is it that takes a second? How are you timing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110689/discussion-between-learningtocode-and-david-griffin).

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on a similar project. But what I did is, I set a timeout and made an agreement that, pass me the offset and number of records u want to get. I will fetch records from the offset you send but I cannot guarantee the number of records we give you. It might fetch less messages if timeout happens. But we give you offset of the last read record so that you can call again with that offset.
(As @David Griffin said, the problem is we have to create new client each time for each partition. OR store your data in only one partition and get it from that partition.

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the maxBytes by 10 or less depends on the size of the message or you can do something like this:

```
if(req.body.off>= req.body.off+10){//return res..}
```